# Вопрос по интерфейсам и классам java

Tags: java, ооп, интерфейс

Допустим есть интерфейс Soldier

```
public interface Soldier {
    String makeCombat();
}
```

Его реализует Infantryman

```
public class Infantryman implements Soldier {

    @Override
    public String makeCombat() {
        return "Combat on foot";
    }
}
```

И еще его реализует Сommander

```
public class Сommander implements Soldier {

private int sizeOfSubordinates = 10;

    @Override
    public String makeCombat() {
        return "Combat on foot and on transport";
    }

public int sizeOfSubordinates() {
        return sizeOfSubordinates ;
    }
}
```

Вопрос в следующем: какой смысл в интерфейсе, если я не смогу вызвать sizeOfSubordinates() если переменная будет типа `Soldier commander = new Commander();` Чтобы можно было его использовать, нужно писать `Commander commander = new Commander();`  Но в таком случае отсутствует полиморфизм и т.д.

Более обобщенно, какой подход использовать, когда у классов есть и общие методы и уникальные для некоторых из классов. Если мне нужны методы не входящие в общий интерфейс, то мне создавать переменную конкретного класса, обходя интерфейс?

Comment: Создайте в интерфейсе `Soldier` `default` метод `sizeOfSubordinates() `, который возвращает 0.

Comment: @Имя а это корректное решение, или скорее костыль?

Comment: Корректное, у солдата же 0 человек в подчинении. Иначе никак не сделать, только новую структуру программы выдумать или отказаться от полиморфизма.

Comment: @Имя понял, спасибо за объяснение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать 2 интерфейса, Soldier и Officer, Soldier содержит метод `makeCombat()`, Officer наследует Soldier и содержит метод `sizeOfSubordinates()`. Таким образом, там где Вам требуется работать с офицерами (командирами, у которых есть подчиненный состав), Вы используете интерфейс Officer, а там где Вам нужен весь личный состав, используете интерфейс Soldier.